# How to arrange input as an object for Extrinsics() function of matlab?

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, camera-calibration, matlab-cvst, perspectivecamera

I am trying to use extrinsics function of matlab to calculate the translation vector. As a requirement i want to give the input camera parameters. i.e. Camera matrix, distortion matrix. But when i give the input i.e. camParam a 3x3 cameraMatrix, it gives me error.

```
camParam = [994.735326361544, 0, 624.663440953582;
            0, 998.166467837258, 364.087425569226;
            0, 0, 1]; 

    [rotationMatrix,translationVector] = extrinsics(left_right_eye_points,(face.model)',camParam);
```

I get the following error:

```
Error using extrinsics
Expected cameraParams to be one of these types:
cameraParameters
Instead its type was double.
Error in extrinsics>checkInputs (line 140)
validateattributes(cameraParams, {'cameraParameters'}, {}, ...
Error in extrinsics (line 91)
checkInputs(imagePoints, worldPoints, cameraParams);
Error in Simple_conversion_from_World_to_Camera_to_image (line 37)
[rotationMatrix,translationVector] = extrinsics(left_right_eye_points,(face.model)',camParam)
```

My question is:

1) how should i arrange my camParam, so that the function extrinsics may accept it.

2) In addition does it also need distortion coefficients? if yes than how to arrange that as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to do what the error message tells you to do. Create a `cameraParameters` object and use it. Probably you want `cp=cameraParameters('IntrinsicMatrix',camParam)`

The cameraParams object also allows you to set a distortion, the documentation explains the details.

Comment: You mean "cp = cameraParameters('IntrinsicMatrix',camParam)"  thanks it worked.

Comment: Yes, fixed my answer.

Comment: yes. you gave me a hint/suggestion, and i further refined it :)

Comment: @khan, when you create the `cameraParameters` object, keep in mind that it assumes 1-based pixel coordinates, meaning that the top-left pxiel's coordinates are [1,1]. Depending on where you got your intrinsics from, you may have to add 1 to the optical center.  Also, try using the Camera Calibrator App: http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/single-camera-calibrator-app.html

Comment: @Dima intrinsic parameters are given with the dataset. Do you think above camParam is not correct.